# How to take html input and display it using external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, output

I have coded a pretty basic page to collect student information (first name, last name, semester, and course name). The first and last name are input type="text"s and the semester and course name are drop down lists.

I now need to use an external JS file to take the text stored in the inputs and display them under registered course as

"First Name Last Name is registered for the following course:
Semester:
Course:"

This is the html code I wrote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>University Registration</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="headerContainer">
       <h1>University Registration System</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <form action="" method="get" class="scInfo">

      <h3>Student and Course Info:</h3>

      <div class="fn">
        <p>First Name: </p>
        <input type="text" name="fn" id="fn" required>
      </div>

      <div class="ln">
        <p>Last Name: </p>
        <input type="text" name="ln" id="ln" required>
      </div>

      <div></div>

      <div class="semester">
        <p>Semester: </p>
        <select>
          <option value="fall">Fall 2019</option>
          <option value="spring">Spring 2020</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="course">
        <p>Course Name: </p>
        <select>
          <option value="365">CIS 365 - Business Database Systems</option>
          <option value="425">CIS 425 - Enterprise Web Technologies</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="button">
        <button id="register">Register</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <h3>Registered Course:</h3>

    <div class="nameOutput">

    </div>

    <div class="semesterOutput">

    </div>

    <div class="classOutput">

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the css code I wrote

```
header h1
{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

form .fn
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

form .ln
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

form .semester
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

form .course
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

form .button
{
  padding: 5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to show the CSS file, as it's not relevant here. This entirely depends on what backend you are using, because you need to get the user to register successfully first, before you output anything onto the screen.

One way to do this, is if you're using a backend API (also you need a POST method, not GET):

```
<form id="registerForm">
...

<input type="submit" value="registerBtn" name="Register" role="button" id="registerBtn">Register Now</button>
```

In your javascript file, you can use an event handler to get the data, send it to your backend API to register the user, and if you get a 200 status code or any equivalent success code, you can display the info back to the user

In your javascript file:

```
const registerForm = document.querySelector("#registerForm")
registerForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from resetting the page
   // grab the input values, and use a request package like axios or javascript's native xmlhttprequest to send the data

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the value from the form itself, then follow the code below.
I have made some changes to your div and select as well.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('registerForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let full_name = document.getElementById('fn').value + ' ' +     document.getElementById('ln').value;
  let name = document.getElementsByClassName('nameOutput')[0];
  name.innerHTML = full_name + 'is registered for the following course';

  let sem = document.getElementById('semester');
  val_sem = sem.options[sem.selectedIndex].text;
  let semester = document.getElementsByClassName('semesterOutput')[0];
  semester.innerHTML = val_sem;

  let cls = document.getElementById('course');
  val_cls = cls.options[cls.selectedIndex].text;
  let classOutput = document.getElementsByClassName('classOutput')[0];
  classOutput.innerHTML = val_cls;
});
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="headerContainer">
       <h1>University Registration System</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <form action="" method="get" class="scInfo" id="registerForm">

      <h3>Student and Course Info:</h3>

      <div class="fn">
        <p>First Name: </p>
        <input type="text" name="fn" id="fn" required>
      </div>

      <div class="ln">
        <p>Last Name: </p>
        <input type="text" name="ln" id="ln" required>
      </div>

      <div></div>

      <div class="semester">
        <p>Semester: </p>
        <select id="semester">
          <option value="fall">Fall 2019</option>
          <option value="spring">Spring 2020</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="course">
        <p>Course Name: </p>
        <select id="course">
          <option value="365">CIS 365 - Business Database Systems</option>
          <option value="425">CIS 425 - Enterprise Web Technologies</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="button">
        <button id="register">Register</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <h3>Registered Course:</h3>

    <div class="nameOutput">
    </div>

    <div class="semesterOutput">

    </div>

    <div class="classOutput">

    </div>
```

I could not insert a external js into the code snippet.But you can just copy the below js into a file and call the file below the same way you have done in your code above.

The output will be displayed when the form will be submitted.There are even better ways to do this, but this is the basic way to achieve it, and also if you are new this will give you some understanding of selectors as well.
Make sure you go through the js code.

Hope this helps

Thanks